# What is the probability that either 1 or 49 is in the winning numbers of a Lotto game?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In a simple Lotto game you have 49 numbers ($1, \ldots, 49$).

$6$ of them get drawn (without multiples, order is not important).

**What is the probability that either the number $1$ or number $49$ get drawn (but not both)?**

### What I know

$$D = \{M: M \subseteq \{1, ..., 49\}, |M| = 6\}$$

$|D| = \binom{49}{6} = \frac{49!}{6!(49-6)!} = (49 \cdot 48 \cdot 47 \cdot 46 \cdot 45 \cdot 44) / (6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1)$, because for the first number you have 49 possibilities, for the second 48, ...
Then you can order each of them. This means the number of orderings has to be divided: The first number can be on 6 different places, the second 5, ...

Answer (score 5):

$$P\left(E_{1}\triangle E_{49}\right)=P\left(E_{1}\right)+P\left(E_{49}\right)-2P\left(E_{1}\cap E_{49}\right)=$$$$P\left(E_{1}\right)+P\left(E_{49}\right)-2P\left(E_{1}\right)P\left(E_{49}\mid E_{1}\right)=\frac{6}{49}+\frac{6}{49}-2.\frac{6}{49}.\frac{5}{48}=\frac{43}{196}$$

Comment: @barakmanos You are now in numerical agreement.

Answer (score 2):

The total number of combinations is $\binom{49}{6}=13983816$

The number of combinations with both $1$ and $49$ is $\binom{47}{4}=178365$

The number of combinations with neither $1$ nor $49$ is $\binom{47}{6}=10737573$

The probability to get either $1$ or $49$ but not both is $\frac{13983816-(178365+10737573)}{13983816}\approx0.219$

Comment: I am confused. The probability that you have both (1 and 49) would be $\frac{\binom{47}{4}}{\binom{49}{6}} = \frac{1}{66}$, the probability that you exactly one is $\frac{43}{56}$ and the probability that you have neither 1 nor 49 would be $\frac{\binom{47}{6}}{\binom{49}{6}} = \frac{13}{56}$. But those should be 1 in sum. Where is the mistake?

Comment: @moose: I think you're wrong with the $\frac{43}{56}$.

Comment: @moose: But I was slightly wrong as well. Please see updated answer...

Answer (score 2):

Generally, the probability of $k$ successes in n draws without replacement from a finite population of size $N$ containing exactly $K$ successes, is described by the [hypergeometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution). 
Its probability mass function (pmf) is given by:
$$P(X=k) = {{{K \choose k} {{N-K} \choose {n-k}}}\over {N \choose n}} $$ for $\max(0, n+K-N) \leq k \leq \min(K,n)$.

---

In your case, you can identify that $N=49, n=6, K=2$ and $k=1$ (since you want exactly one success). Hence, the required probability is equal to $$P(X=1) = {{{2 \choose 1} {{49-2} \choose {6-1}}}\over {49 \choose 6}}=\frac{2\cdot43\cdot6}{48\cdot49}=0.219388$$